# ListView DataBind Sorting Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to have a `DropdownMenu` from which i can choose how i want to sort my `ListView`. 
This is my current code for it :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GetProducts">
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="DesDate"> Descending Date </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="AsDate"> Ascending Date </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="AsAlp"> Ascending Alphabetical </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="DesAlp"> Decentind Alphabetical </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And I have this `ListView` to display my data:

```
<asp:ListView ID="productList" runat="server" 
     DataKeyNames="NewsID" GroupItemCount="1"
     ItemType="SiteStiri.Models.News" SelectMethod="GetProducts">
       <EmptyDataTemplate>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </EmptyDataTemplate>
       <EmptyItemTemplate>
          <td/>
       </EmptyItemTemplate>
       <GroupTemplate>
          <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
              <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
          </tr>
       </GroupTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <td runat="server">
       <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="NewsDetails.aspx?newsID=<%#:Item.NewsID%>">
                 <img src="/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ImagePath%>"
             width="100" height="75" style="border: solid" /></a>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
            <a href="NewsDetails.aspx?newsID=<%#:Item.NewsID%>">
               <p style="color: black;">
                  <%#:Item.NewsTitle%>
               </p>
            </a>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
      </p>
     </td>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <LayoutTemplate>
       <table style="width:100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
               <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
                    style="width:100%">
                 <tr id="groupPlaceholder"></tr>
               </table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         <tr></tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
     </LayoutTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

The thing that i have no idea how to do is:
 After selecting a sorting rule from the dropdown menu, i can't figure out how to write(or where to write) the method that would update my ListView as it should. My attemp is :

```
 public IQueryable<News> GetProducts()
        {
            var _db = new SiteStiri.Models.NewsContext();
            IQueryable<News> query = _db.News;

            if (("DesDate").Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query.OrderByDescending(u => u.ReleaseDate);
            }
            if (("AsDate").Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query.OrderBy(u => u.ReleaseDate);
            }
            if (("AsAlp").Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query.OrderBy(u => u.NewsTitle);
            }
            if (("DesApl").Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                query.OrderByDescending(u => u.NewsTitle);
            }


            return query;
        }
```

which gives me a bunch of errors and it doesn't even work .... a little bit of help please? I am new to this (2 days).

Comment: Here's somewhere to start: `.OrderBy` and `.OrderByDescending` do not sort in place: they return a new object.  So you need to assign the result of `query.OrderBy(etc)` to a variable and return that variable.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! i was on the right track but probably couldn't have figured out the query = query.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fix your code step by step.

1. Event handlers need to have a certain signature. In case of every ASP.NET control I can remember of, they need to receive two parameters, event arguments and event source object, and return void. Also note that just calling `GetProduct` is not going to update `ListView`, we need to trigger databinding for the control itself. We'll get to that later. For now let's introduce a proper handler:

   ```
   public void DropDownSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   ```

   Don't forget to update markup as well:

   ```
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownSelect_SelectedIndexChanged"
   ```
2. The conditions on how you show data in the `ListView` have changed. That means that you need to rebind it with calling `DataBind`, which should call `GetProducts` (as a one specified in `SelectMethod`):

   ```
   public void DropDownSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       productList.DataBind();
   }
   ```
3. Finally in `GetProducts` note that LINQ calls do not update the current object, but rather they produce new one every time. So you should have something like this:

   ```
   if ("DesDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
   {
       query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.ReleaseDate);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me ! your pointers where more than anyone could have asked! <3 (well what you told me was more of a full solution than pointers :)) )

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the data and not the query right?  That code would look like this, all you have to do is parse the selected value and pass it into the method.  If the ListView is bound to the data (and it should be) you're all set.  This example shows the separation of concerns, whereby the view is just a framework for HOW to show the data, and the code behind is a framework for WHAT data is supplied based on triggers from the view.  The trigger in this case is the "filter" parameter.

```
List<News> query = _db.News.ToList();
public List<News> GetProduct(string filter) {

    if (filter == "DesDate") return query.OrderByDescending(u => ReleaseDate).ToList();

}
```

One last note: IQueryable is a class that lets you pass queries around, you can alter the query itself from method to method.  But this class does not produce results until it is told to do so by using any of the To methods like ToList(), ToArray(), ToLookup() and or any attempt to iterate over it such as:

```
Foreach(var thing in MyQuerable){  //results are here }
```